# NavigationBar Right Button is not Appearing

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I assigned Custom Class to navigationbar but right button is not appearing on navbar.
Here is the code if anyone can help will be appreciated.

```
class BaseNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.white
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "contact_us"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(callSupport))
        self.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(hexString: "#37C54D")
        self.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @objc func callSupport() {
        print("Button Pressed")
    }

}
```

Comment: You should set the rightBarButtonItem in your viewController rather than the navigationController.

Comment: Because of this I have to add that button in 50 View Controllers.
Any other solution?

Comment: You can create a BaseViewController -> set rightBarButtonItem and all ViewController will inherit from it

Comment: any example and where I will assign that base viewcontroller?

Answer (score 0):

@Muhammad Hasan Irshad
BaseViewController:
[image: BaseViewController].

A sample ViewController:
[image: A sample ViewController].

Comment: Thanks for guidance but it's the same thing, Need to assign it 50 vc.